# pyqt vtk: How to remove the margin?

Tags: pyqt5, vtk

I am using pyqt5+vtk in my program, and the code is:

```
import sys
import vtk

from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *

from vtk.qt.QVTKRenderWindowInteractor import QVTKRenderWindowInteractor

class MainWindow(QWidget):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__()
        self.setStyleSheet('background-color: rgb(255,0,0)')
        self.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.frame = QFrame()

        self.vl = QVBoxLayout()
        self.setLayout(self.vl)
        self.vtkWidget = QVTKRenderWindowInteractor(self.frame)
        self.vtkWidget.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.vl.addWidget(self.vtkWidget)

        self.ren = vtk.vtkRenderer()
        self.vtkWidget.GetRenderWindow().AddRenderer(self.ren)
        self.iren = self.vtkWidget.GetRenderWindow().GetInteractor()

        # Create source
        source = vtk.vtkSphereSource()
        source.SetCenter(0, 0, 0)
        source.SetRadius(5.0)

        # Create a mapper
        mapper = vtk.vtkPolyDataMapper()
        mapper.SetInputConnection(source.GetOutputPort())

        # Create an actor
        actor = vtk.vtkActor()
        actor.SetMapper(mapper)

        self.ren.AddActor(actor)

        self.ren.ResetCamera()

        self.show()
        self.iren.Initialize()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    window = MainWindow()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

This code has no bug, and the result is:

[image]

The only problem is that the vtk window do not occupy all qt window (please look at the red color). I have tried `self.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)`, but it do not work.

Is there any method to remove the margin? It is appreciated for any suggestion.

Comment: Is the red border painted by you? Have you tried to also set the *layout*'s contents margins with `self.vl.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)`? Also, why are you adding a QFrame as a parent? Can't you just add the `QVTKRenderWindowInteractor` instance alone?

Comment: That solve my problem. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing to do with vtk, but with Qt layouts.

Everytime a layout is set on a widget, Qt adds default margins depending on the widget's (or application's) [`style()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#style).

On most platforms it's a range between 6 and 10 pixels, and in order to avoid it the contents margins must be explictly set to 0 *for the layout*:

```
self.vl.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
```